# Java Client to C# server. Not receiving negative numbers

Tags: java, c#, networking, tcp, byte

I have a Java app sending coordinates to a c# game in Unity. My data checks out with the exception of the negative values. I instead only get 63 or 250 something. Depending on the encoding.

Here is my Java client app:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    //Keep in a loop as long as the running variable is true
    while(running)
    {
        //Try catch block to catch exceptions for the networking code
        try{
            data1[0]=currentPlayer; // These are integers
            .....
            data1[8]=sendPause;

            for(int i=0; i<=9;i++){
                buf1[i]=(byte)data1[i];     //Casting to byte array
                //System.out.println(buf1[i]);
            }
            //socket is created in "onCreate" earlier
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
            dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

            dos.write(buf1, 0, buf1.length);
            dos.flush();
            synchronized(this){ this.wait(30); } //This is to minimize the frequency 


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("TCP", "Error",e);
            }
        }

    }
```

This is my method for receiving in the C# server.

```
private void HandleClient(TcpClient client){
    try{
        byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
        String data = null;

        while(true) 
        {
            data = null;
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;
            while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
            {   
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

                /*sbyte[] sbytes = new sbyte[msg.Length];
                for (int j = 0; j < msg.Length; j++)
                    sbytes[j] = (sbyte)msg[j];
                Debug.Log(sbytes[2]+" "+sbytes[3]);*/
                packetID=msg[0];
                switch(packetID){
                case 1:
                    p1.joyLx = msg[1];
                    ....
                    p1.pause = msg[8];
                    p1.active=true;
                    break;
                ....
                case 4:
                    p4.joyLx = msg[1];
                    ....
                    p4.active=true;
                    break;         
                }
            }
            client.Close();
        }
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
        Debug.Log("SocketException:"+e);
    }
}
```

I've been looking into the whole signed/unsigned byte ordeal but I'm worried that upon saving it into a byte array beforehand is erasing this data.

P.S. this is my first visit here and I'm not really a programmer so I've probably missed something obvious. So sorry if I'm not accustomed...

Got it working! Thanks for the help and pointing out my oddities!

```
[...]byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
        sbyte[] sbytes;

        while(true) 
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;
            while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
            {   
                sbytes = new sbyte[bytes.Length];
                for (int j = 0; j < bytes.Length; j++)
                    sbytes[j] = (sbyte)bytes[j];
                packetID=bytes[0]; [...]
```

Comment: Do you really need to use encoding on C# side. Do you use any strings in messages?

Comment: Your received data is already in `bytes`. Your first convert it to string(losing some info) and then convert it back to byte array. Meaningless...

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out this. I was trying out a bunch of stuff, but it was only hindering me. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using a byte array in your C# code. A byte in java has a range of -128 to 127. A byte in C# ranges from 0 to 255. Try copying the received byte array into an sbyte array:

```
 sbyte[] signedB = new sbyte[bytes.Length];
 Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, signedB, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Check the values of signedB after this.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but in that case I can't use the stream.Read function since it only takes byte, not sbyte. "System.IO.Stream.Read(byte[], int, int)"

Comment: Yes, I got it working just before you posted again. Will try out your solution too. Thanks for the help